# IntelliJ community maven pom.xml error suggesting cucumber jar version conflicts

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, cucumber

I get this version conflict error in my maven pom.xml file:

**Could not resolve version conflict among [io.cucumber:cucumber-core:jar:6.11.0 -> io.cucumber:messages:jar:15.0.0, io.cucumber:cucumber-core:jar:6.11.0 -> io.cucumber:html-formatter:jar:13.0.0 -> io.cucumber:messages:jar:[15.0.0,16.0.0), io.cucumber:cucumber-core:jar:6.11.0 -> io.cucumber:create-meta:jar:4.0.0 -> io.cucumber:messages:jar:[15.0.0,16.0.0), io.cucumber:gherkin:jar:21.0.0 -> io.cucumber:messages:jar:[17.1.0,18.0.0)]**

here is the complete pom.xml code, please help to fix this, using IntelliJ community 2021.2.2

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>SeleniumCucumber</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>6.11.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.11.0</version>
        </dependency>




        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-html -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-html</artifactId>
            <version>0.2.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sourceforge.cobertura/cobertura -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.cobertura</groupId>
            <artifactId>cobertura</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>



        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.0-RC1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-jvm-deps -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-deps</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.6</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.masterthought/cucumber-reporting -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hamcrest/hamcrest-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/gherkin -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>gherkin</artifactId>
            <version>21.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.13.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

</project>
```

***after updating the gherkin version to 18.0.0 the dependency part was fixed but while running the test runner I get the following error:***

**"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_301\bin\java.exe" -ea -DnodeNamesHandler=org.jetbrains.plugins.cucumber.java.run.CucumberTestTreeNodeManager -Didea.test.cyclic.buffer.size=1048576 "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.2.2\lib\idea_rt.jar=57593:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.2.2\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.2.2\lib\idea_rt.jar;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.2.2\plugins\junit\lib\junit5-rt.jar;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.2.2\plugins\junit\lib\junit-rt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_301\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_301\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_301\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_301\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_301\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_301\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_301\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_301\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_301\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_301\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_301\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_301\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_301\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_301\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_301\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_301\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_301\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_301\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_301\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_301\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_301\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_301\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_301\jre\lib\rt.jar;D:\selenium\projects\BDD_Cucucmber\target\test-classes;C:\Users\mangesh.m2\repository\io\cucumber\cucumber-java\5.6.0\cucumber-java-5.6.0.jar;C:\Users\mangesh.m2\repository\io\cucumber\cucumber-core\5.6.0\cucumber-core-5.6.0.jar;C:\Users\mangesh.m2\repository\io\cucumber\cucumber-gherkin\5.6.0\cucumber-gherkin-5.6.0.jar;C:\Users\mangesh.m2\repository\io\cucumber\cucumber-gherkin-vintage\5.6.0\cucumber-gherkin-vintage-5.6.0.jar;C:\Users\mangesh.m2\repository\io\cucumber\tag-expressions\2.0.4\tag-expressions-2.0.4.jar;C:\Users\mangesh.m2\repository\io\cucumber\cucumber-expressions\8.3.1\cucumber-expressions-8.3.1.jar;C:\Users\mangesh.m2\repository\io\cucumber\datatable\3.3.1\datatable-3.3.1.jar;C:\Users\mangesh.m2\repository\io\cucumber\cucumber-plugin\5.6.0\cucumber-plugin-5.6.0.jar;C:\Users\mangesh.m2\repository\io\cucumber\docstring\5.6.0\docstring-5.6.0.jar;C:\Users\mangesh.m2\repository\org\apiguardian\apiguardian-api\1.1.0\apiguardian-api-1.1.0.jar;C:\Users\mangesh.m2\repository\junit\junit\4.11\junit-4.11.jar;C:\Users\mangesh.m2\repository\org\hamcrest\hamcrest-core\1.3\hamcrest-core-1.3.jar;C:\Users\mangesh.m2\repository\io\cucumber\cucumber-junit\7.0.0-RC1\cucumber-junit-7.0.0-RC1.jar;C:\Users\mangesh.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-api\3.141.59\selenium-api-3.141.59.jar;C:\Users\mangesh.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-chrome-driver\3.141.59\selenium-chrome-driver-3.141.59.jar;C:\Users\mangesh.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-remote-driver\3.141.59\selenium-remote-driver-3.141.59.jar;C:\Users\mangesh.m2\repository\net\bytebuddy\byte-buddy\1.8.15\byte-buddy-1.8.15.jar;C:\Users\mangesh.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-exec\1.3\commons-exec-1.3.jar;C:\Users\mangesh.m2\repository\com\google\guava\guava\25.0-jre\guava-25.0-jre.jar;C:\Users\mangesh.m2\repository\com\google\code\findbugs\jsr305\1.3.9\jsr305-1.3.9.jar;C:\Users\mangesh.m2\repository\org\checkerframework\checker-compat-qual\2.0.0\checker-compat-qual-2.0.0.jar;C:\Users\mangesh.m2\repository\com\google\errorprone\error_prone_annotations\2.1.3\error_prone_annotations-2.1.3.jar;C:\Users\mangesh.m2\repository\com\google\j2objc\j2objc-annotations\1.1\j2objc-annotations-1.1.jar;C:\Users\mangesh.m2\repository\org\codehaus\mojo\animal-sniffer-annotations\1.14\animal-sniffer-annotations-1.14.jar;C:\Users\mangesh.m2\repository\com\squareup\okhttp3\okhttp\3.11.0\okhttp-3.11.0.jar;C:\Users\mangesh.m2\repository\com\squareup\okio\okio\1.14.0\okio-1.14.0.jar;C:\Users\mangesh\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\IdeaIC2021.2\plugins\cucumber-java\lib\cucumber-jvmFormatter.jar" com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter -ideVersion5 -junit4 TestRunner.testRunner
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: io.cucumber.junit.JUnitCucumberOptionsProvider$JunitCucumberOptions.tags()[Ljava/lang/String;
at io.cucumber.core.options.CucumberOptionsAnnotationParser.addTags(CucumberOptionsAnnotationParser.java:90)
at io.cucumber.core.options.CucumberOptionsAnnotationParser.parse(CucumberOptionsAnnotationParser.java:51)
at io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber.(Cucumber.java:120)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:29)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:21)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:26)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:50)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)**

Comment: Use a version of gherkin which works with an earlier version of messages, e.g. 18.0.0

Comment: hi thanks for the reply...i had tried that but it can only identify gherkin 21...is there anyway i can download the jar and add it as dependency ??

Comment: What problem do you have using other versions? They seem to be there, e.g. https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/gherkin/18.0.0

Comment: @tgdavies when i am removing 21.0.0 and updating it with 18.0.0 build gives another error that 18.0.0 is not found

Comment: What maven command are you using and what exact, complete error message do you get? I have no trouble getting 18.0.0. Do you have some special ~/.mvn/settings.xml repository configuration?

Comment: i did a restrt and after that pom.xml updated  gherkin version to 18.0.0...but when running the test runner i get the other errors..i have updated it in the description above

Comment: As @M.P. Korstanje says in his answer below, use consistent versions. You're not using the same version of cucumber-core and cucumber-unit.

Answer (score 3):

Your dependencies are inconsistent. You are mixing multiple versions of Cucumber and including transitive dependencies.

So I would strongly urge you to invest time in learning how to use Maven (or Gradle) beyond a superficial level. Understanding these tools and the concepts involved can make your life much easier.

For example:

If you want to use Cucumber with JUnit 4 and annotation based step definitions you would declare this minimal set of dependencies in a Maven `pom.xml` file.

(Note: Copied an example with an older version, doesn't matter for the explanation)

```
    <properties>
        <cucumber.version>5.2.0</cucumber.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

By telling Maven what your dependencies are Maven can calculate your transitive dependencies i.e: the dependencies of your dependencies.

This has many advantages. One example would be using the `mvn dependency:tree` command to will list all dependencies and their transitive dependencies.

```
$ mvn dependency:tree
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------< cucumber:cucumber-java-skeleton >-------------------
[INFO] Building Cucumber-Java Skeleton 0.0.1
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ cucumber-java-skeleton ---
[INFO] cucumber:cucumber-java-skeleton:jar:0.0.1
[INFO] +- io.cucumber:cucumber-java:jar:5.2.0:test
[INFO] |  +- io.cucumber:cucumber-core:jar:5.2.0:test
[INFO] |  |  +- io.cucumber:cucumber-gherkin:jar:5.2.0:test
[INFO] |  |  +- io.cucumber:cucumber-gherkin-vintage:jar:5.2.0:test
[INFO] |  |  +- io.cucumber:tag-expressions:jar:2.0.4:test
[INFO] |  |  +- io.cucumber:cucumber-expressions:jar:8.3.1:test
[INFO] |  |  +- io.cucumber:datatable:jar:3.3.0:test
[INFO] |  |  +- io.cucumber:cucumber-plugin:jar:5.2.0:test
[INFO] |  |  \- io.cucumber:docstring:jar:5.2.0:test
[INFO] |  \- org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:jar:1.1.0:test
[INFO] +- io.cucumber:cucumber-junit:jar:5.2.0:test
[INFO] \- junit:junit:jar:4.13:test
[INFO]    \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  0.781 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-02-10T23:00:14+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: thanks a lot explaing this...i was following a youtube tutorial to learn cucumber setup in intellij . I have no previous experience with maven as such..but I will try to learn it in depth...if you can help me with any good source that can help the dependency part please suggest me ..

Comment: https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/index.html this wouldn't be a bad start but it implicitly assumes you've created at least one small java project from scratch without advanced tooling

Comment: Then this looks alright for doing a project without tooling https://dev.to/martingaston/understanding-the-java-classpath-building-a-project-manually-3c3l

Comment: thanks a lot for your help and and your time to answer my questions