# Unable to run cucumber features in parallel using Maven Surefire and Failsafe plugins

Tags: maven, pom.xml, maven-surefire-plugin, cucumber-junit, maven-failsafe-plugin

I am facing issue in running my cucumber feature files in parallel.

I went through several tutorials / posts / blogs and they all recommend to use Maven surefire / failsafe plugin to run them in parallel. I tried that as well but still no luck.

Below is my code:

```
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <junit.version>4.13.2</junit.version>
        <cucumber.version>6.9.1</cucumber.version>
        <maven.compiler.version>3.8.1</maven.compiler.version>
        <maven.surefire.version>2.22.2</maven.surefire.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.13.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-deps</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>gherkin</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>
<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>-->
<!--            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>-->
<!--            <scope>test</scope>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.20</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-schema-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-jwt</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0-alpha5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.27</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.dzieciou.testing</groupId>
            <artifactId>curl-logger</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
            <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.22.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
            <artifactId>extentreports-cucumber4-adapter</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.relevantcodes</groupId>
            <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
            <version>2.41.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.vincentrussell</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-data-generator</artifactId>
            <version>1.16</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
            <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.awaitility</groupId>
            <artifactId>awaitility</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.compiler.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.surefire.version}</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <configuration>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/TestRunner.java</include>
                            </includes>
                            <parallel>methods</parallel>
                            <threadCount>4</threadCount>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Below is my Runner file:

```
@CucumberOptions(
        features= {"src/test/resources/features/"}
        ,glue = {"com.project.api.stepdefinition"},
        plugin = {"pretty:target/cucumber/cucumber.txt",
                "json:target/cucumber/cucumber.json",
                "com.project.reporting.ReportListener"
        }
        //,dryRun = true
        ,monochrome = true
        ,snippets = SnippetType.CAMELCASE
        ,tags = "@Organization"
        ,publish = true
        )
```

In my @Before annotation (Which runs before every Scenario), I am printing the current thread ID and every time I am getting Thread ID as 1 and all Scenarios of all features are running sequentially.

Can someone please help me out here as what I am doing wrong.

Thanks

Comment: First you should read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example because this question has way too much information that make it easy for anyone to answer.

Comment: Then you should read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69234566/intellij-community-maven-pom-xml-error-suggesting-cucumber-jar-version-conflicts/69235426#69235426 because the way you are using Maven will cause you grief later on.

Comment: Then you can start a new project by using https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-java-skeleton

Comment: And finally make that new project work in parallel by reading *all of* https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/main/cucumber-junit-platform-engine

Comment: I got the problem now, they are running in parallel but dependency injection (PICO Container library I am using) is not working as expected in multiple threads. Any reference for this problem? @M.P.Korstanje

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "not working as expected". There could be a bug, you may be making a mistake, or your expectation might be wrong. You would be better of making a new question following the guidelines from https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example